# What do I need to know before buying a bike off of Craigslist?

Tags: road-bike, commuter, used-bike

I know absolutely nothing about bicycles yet I need to buy one in the next 7-9 days. I really can't afford to buy one new and my price range is in the $100-$150 area. Craiglist is my best bet for getting a decent value for my money so what should I know, check, and say when talking to the bike owners?

The one I have been eyeing is the Marin Road Bike in the first image in the description on this link:
http://fresno.craigslist.org/bik/3856785558.html

Comment: That is definitely a duplicate.